# How to add/write a heading to an .txt file

Tags: python

I am trying to add a heading to my newly created .txt file with an outfile command. However, my intended heading ("Teams Wins Losses") doesn't appear on the first line, rather, it is preceding each line of data.

Code:

```
def newfile(teams):
     outfile = open("OrderedALE.txt", 'w')
     for team in teams:
        outfile.write("Teams Wins Losses")
        outfile.write(team[0] + ',' + str(team[1]) + ',' +
                      str(team[2]) + ',' + str(round(team[1]/162, 3)) + "\n")

outfile.close()
```

Output:

```
Teams Wins LossesBaltimore,96,66,0.593
Teams Wins LossesNew York,84,78,0.519
Teams Wins LossesToronto,83,79,0.512
Teams Wins LossesTampa Bay,77,85,0.475
Teams Wins LossesBoston,71,91,0.438
```

Comment: Move the header before the loop.

Comment: Put `outfile.write("Teams Wins Losses")` before the for loop, not inside it

Comment: Don't forget to add a newline

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
def newfile(teams):
 outfile = open("OrderedALE.txt", 'w')
 outfile.write("Teams Wins Losses")
  for team in teams:
    outfile.write(team[0] + ',' + str(team[1]) + ',' +
    str(team[2]) + ',' + str(round(team[1]/162, 3)) + "\n")

outfile.close()
```

Should be written like this:

Use the `with` keyword, it ensures that the resources are cleaned up at the end.

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write("Teams Wins Losses")
    # add a new line after the heading
    f.write("\n")
     for team in teams:
         f.write("{0},{1},{2},{3}".format(team[0]),team[1],team[2],round(team[1]/162, 3))
         # add a new line after each output
         f.write("\n")
```

**Note:**
As pointed out in the comments using `+` to concat strings can have negative side effects. Many pages on SO explain this topic, instead use `.format()` to display your `strings`

Comment: Please don't construct strings using `+`

Comment: @StephenRauch - the OP did that, not me, I never suggested it either.

Comment: And don't the comments give the same answer? :)

Comment: I realize the OP did it.  But hopefully you know better, and can demonstrate reasonable Python. If you are going to construct an answer, please construct a good one.  Thank you.

Comment: I moved the heading statement and my output looks like this...         
Teams Wins LossesBaltimore,96,66,0.593
New York,84,78,0.519
Toronto,83,79,0.512
Tampa Bay,77,85,0.475
Boston,71,91,0.438

Comment: @user9327806 - edit your question, it's confusing to have code in the comments.

Comment: @user9327806 - Based on your comment you need to add a new line.

Comment: Your indent is a bit off, and you likely don't need the `str()` in the format as that should just happen.  Suggest you get in the habit of running the code in your answers to be confident they are right.

Comment: You are forgetting a newline, which write doesn't append for you.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - Fixed

Comment: @QueenSvetlana. No it's not.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - It works for me, what do you see as wrong?

Comment: There's no newline after the heading

Comment: @MadPhysicist - Now?

Comment: Almost. You forgot the first example. BTW, you can just use `print(..., file=f)` for stuff like this. It's a much cleaner interface in my opinion (and just wraps `f.write` under the hood).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an appendix to [@QueenSvetlana's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48918892/2988730). In addition to using a `with` block, you could also consider using `print` instead of `f.write`. The interface is cleaner (separators and newlines are inserted automatically). It also removes the need to create formatted strings in-memory to avoid multiple calls to `write`:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    print("Teams Wins Losses", file=f)
    for team in teams:
        print(*team, round(team[1] / 162, 3), sep=',', file=f)
```

This approach is less flexible than using direct writes, but turns out to be more concise in this case.